# Customer and Contact columns in PXCustomSelectorAttribute

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created a custom selector attribute, that filters what customers will appear in the popup box based on the user's ID.

But I have run into the problem that I can't seem to customize it like a normal selector
ie:

```
 [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<InventoryItem.inventoryID, LeftJoin<INItemQtyCost, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<INItemQtyCost.inventoryID>>>>),
        typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD), typeof(InventoryItem.descr), typeof(INItemQtyCost.qtyAvail)
        SubstituteKey = typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
        Filterable = true)]
```

And can only use my custom selector attribute like this:

```
 [SalesRepCustomer]
```

The constructor for the PXCustomSelectorAttribute is as follows:

```
public SalesRepCustomer() : base(typeof(Customer.bAccountID))
    {
        this.DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName);
        this.SubstituteKey = typeof(Customer.acctCD);          
    }
```

Is there a way to use the search2<> and so on in a PXCustomSelectorAttribute?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a PXCustomSelectorAttribute is to override the "GetItems" method where you define the search function used to return records:

From https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/09/custom-selector-attribute.html

```
public class CustomerPriceClassAttribute : PXCustomSelectorAttribute
{
    public CustomerPriceClassAttribute()
        : base(typeof(ARPriceClass.priceClassID))
    {
            this.DescriptionField = typeof(ARPriceClass.description);
    }
    protected virtual IEnumerable GetRecords()
    {
        foreach (ARPriceClass pc in PXSelect<ARPriceClass>.Select(this._Graph))
        {
            yield return pc;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use PXSelectJoin or other PXSelect classes if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Utilization of the `PXSelectorAttribute`

```
public class SalesRepCustomer : PXSelectorAttribute
{
    public SalesRepCustomer() : base(typeof(Search<Customer.bAccountID>))
    {
    }
}
```

Usage would be as follows :

```
public class BatchExtension : PXCacheExtension<Batch>
{
    public abstract class usrSalesRepCustomerID : BqlInt.Field<usrSalesRepCustomerID>
    {
    }
    [SalesRepCustomer(SubstituteKey = typeof(Customer.acctName), DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.legalName))]
    public int? UsrSalesRepCustomerID
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```